# Why is x not bound in (define lambda (lambda (x) x))?

Tags: scheme

I tried to evaluate this: `(define lambda (lambda (x) x))`. MIT Scheme 11.2 gives an error: `;Unbound variable: x`. Chez Scheme 9.5 also gives an error: `Exception: variable x is not bound`. Why is `x` not bound? I thought that `define` would evaluate `(lambda (x) x)` into an anonymous function, and then define `lambda` to be that anonymous function. Where does `x` get involved?

I don't get any errors in Racket 7.2 and Guile 3.0.1.

Comment: and what happens for `(define list (list 1 2))`? besides, why would you ever want to write such a code? nobody ever would / should, so if a certain implementation has troubles with it, so what? :)

Comment: @adabsurdum yes. it is much less severe with `list`, as you say, so maybe it't not that bad. that wasn't the most successful illustration. :) still it brought the point across, hopefully. to do that with `lambda` though ..... _why??_ :)

Comment: @WillNess -- originally I thought that the problem was attempting to use a keyword where a variable was expected in the `define` form, but that didn't sit quite right. It seems that the problem was really connected to redefining a keyword in a way that relies on the original binding of that keyword for the meaning of the new definition.

Comment: @adabsurdum ah, so my guess was pretty close, huh. :) thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't valid Scheme code:

```lisp
(define lambda (lambda (x) x))
```

R7RS seems pretty clear about forbidding this in Section 5.4 about syntax definitions:

> However, it is an error for a definition to define an identifier whose binding has to be known in order to determine the meaning of the definition itself, or of any preceding definition that belongs to the same group of internal definitions.

In the posted code the identifer `lambda` is being redefined, but the binding of `lambda` itself must be known in order to determine the meaning of the new definition; the above language forbids this.

R6RS has some similar language in [Chapter 10](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-13.html#node_chap_10) about the expansion process, but the R6RS language is more tightly coupled to the technical details of the expansion process. I'm *pretty* sure that it applies in the same way to this case, but not 100% sure.

> A definition in the sequence of forms must not define any identifier whose binding is used to determine the meaning of the undeferred portions of the definition or any definition that precedes it in the sequence of forms.

OP notes the error message *`Exception: variable x is not bound`* and asks: "*Where does x get involved?*"

Granting that `(define lambda (lambda (x) x))` is malformed and thus not valid Scheme, it isn't *too* meaningful to try to explain such behaviors. Yet it seems that this sort of behavior can be triggered by attempting to redefine other syntactic keywords in similar fashion. Consider:

```
> (define if (if x y z))
Exception: variable z is not bound
```

It seems obvious here that `z` is unbound, so the error doesn't seem unreasonable. But now:

```
> (define if (if #t 1 2))
Exception: variable if is not bound
```

Even `if` is unbound in the right-hand expression of the `define` form! If we assume that something similar is happening in `(define lambda (lambda (x) x))` then `lambda` is unbound in the right-hand expression, and if that is the case, then `(lambda (x) x)` is *not* evaluated as a special form, but as an ordinary procedure call. The order of evaluation for arguments in a procedure call is unspecified, so it is perfectly reasonable that `x` could be reported as unbound before `lambda` in this case. We can get rid of the appearances of unbound `x`s to see if `lambda` is being bound:

```
> (define lambda (lambda))
Exception: variable lambda is not bound

> (define lambda lambda)
Exception: variable lambda is not bound
```

So it seems that the problem here is that attempting to redefine a syntactic keyword using an expression that relies on that keyword for its meaning can cause the binding for the syntactic keyword to become inaccessible.

In any case, take this last bit with a grain of salt because in the end this sort of redefinition is not valid code, and no particular behavior should be expected of it.